# jQuery not defined on line 338... what's going on here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to import jQuery, but for some reason, it's not letting me, and it's giving me the following error:

`[10:16:02.965] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ http://127.0.0.1:8020/project/js/jquery-191.js:338`

I don't have any javascript that occurs before I import jQuery, which seems to be the reason most people get the "reference error". Here's my code under the`<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Home | Howard University Astronomy</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--get javascript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-191.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: can someone explain why I'm getting downvoted for a legitimate question that I'm providing all the documentation for, answering all the questions presented to, and that hasn't been answered by a previous question?

Comment: Well, does jQuery live at http://127.0.0.1:8020/project/js/jquery-191.js?

Comment: Are you sure of the path ?

Comment: Try to re-download jQuery.  Was your version modified?

Comment: Probably your path is wrong.

Comment: @j08691 it does, yeah.I wish it were that simple

Comment: Does `jquery-191.js` contain anything besides just jQuery?  Plugins?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Just jquery, I downloaded it straight from their download page.

Comment: What does line `338` of your jQuery file show? Perhaps also include a few lines before and after as well.

Comment: Do you have any JS later on in the page? Can you show it?

Comment: @Novocaine88 I haven't written any javascript on my page yet... so no.

Comment: Can you try linking to, say, a Google-hosted copy of jquery, and see if that works? https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=ja#jquery

Comment: @Lily that works! It's a bit frustrating, however, because I would prefer to NOT use an external server.

Comment: @paintedcones Fair enough! What happens if you download the google page and host that yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have said you dont want to rely on an external server which is a good idea at its core but doesn't take advantage of the fact that most people have jquery cached in their browsers through the most popular CDN.

There is an extra trick you can do which is to use a fallback copy if the CDN fails:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

(Note: I changed the MS hosted snippet Scott provided to Google [because of this post](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/))

As to your actual problem it seems like you might have got a dodgy copy of the jquery.js file as its not a standard naming pattern i've seen before so wondering if its been messed up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your script link with this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-191.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. However, linking to a google hosted version did. I just don't want to rely on an external server.... hmm...

Comment: Are you developing on a local server?

Comment: I'm developing using Aptana studio, which allows me to use a local server... so yes.

Comment: I use Aptana too. Are you able to run it on a WAMP server? That would give a bit of a better idea as to what would happen on a live server. Also you would be able to use 'http://localhost/yoursite/js/jquery-191.js' as your source link (not a relative link).

Comment: I actually was able to figure it out using rtpHarry's advice below... Thanks for your help!!

Comment: That's great, just a word of advice: don't use document.write for that. That is bad practice as it writes to document disregarding everything else that is already there. A little dangerous to use it. But otherwise, great stuff!